# Как скомпилировать bundle.js без ssh доступа в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ssh, компиляция

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. На хостинге стоит проект на Laravel, все было хорошо, пока не решили использовать в нем vue.js.
Для компиляции скрипта требуется использовать команды по типу "npm run watch", но хостинг не предоставляет ssh доступа.
Как то можно решить эту проблему и скомпилировать скрипт без перехода на VMS?
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Скорее всего никак, если у хостера нет на машине npm (и даже если и есть, он вряд ли доступен Вам). Можно попробовать из PHP вызывать команды консоли через exec (опять же, если хостер не запретил exec в конфигах PHP, а он скорее всего запретил для безопасности). В любом случае, лучше возьмите VDS уже и не мучайтесь. Они стоят не сильно дороже хостинга.

Comment: Соберите локально `npm run prod` и закидывайте уже собранные файлы из папки public на хостинг.